# Load multiple picture files with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, file

I found this useful [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm) which shows how to load picture from your local pc with a directive (newbie w/angular). But I don't know where to modify it to display also the selected images. How could I achieve this? I found that many examples like this that only lists the filenames.

I found this [approach](http://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/CfilG) which loads the file and I adapted it to load multiple files. By this doesn't use angular.

```
window.onload = function() {

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');


    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var imageType = /image.*/;

        if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "";

                var img = new Image();
                img.src = reader.result;

                fileDisplayArea.appendChild(img);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
        } else {
            fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "File not supported!"
        }
    });
```

What would be a better approach. I want to load multiple files, display and finally upload them as byteArray.

Comment: Here is one idea: Use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of reading it as base64

Comment: Here is another idea: Use `accept="image/*"` [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept) so user can only select image from the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will allow selection of multiple files and display them on the webpage. For uploading them you can use Formdata Here is the link to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) . Also you can find several post  explaining how to upload files using FormData you just have to ask Google.

```js
window.onload = function(){
        
    //Check File API support
    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
    {
        var filesInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
        
        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){
            
            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
            var output = document.getElementById("fileDisplayArea");
            output.innerHTML="";
            for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];
                
                //Only pics
                if(!file.type.match('image'))
                  continue;
                
                var picReader = new FileReader();
                
                picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){
                    
                    var picFile = event.target;
                    
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    
                    div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                            "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";
                    
                    output.insertBefore(div,null);            
                
                });
                
                 //Read the image
                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }                               
           
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #333;
}

#page-wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  border-top: 5px solid #69c773;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

h1 {
 margin-top: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#fileDisplayArea {
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">

 <h1>Image File Reader</h1>
 <div>
  Select an image file: 
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple>
 </div>
 <div id="fileDisplayArea"></div>

</div>
```